# Disable observers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a sidekiq process which sends an email and that works, and I have an observer which performs this sidekiq after an user is created.

```
class UserObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer

  def after_create user
    UserMailer.delay.welcome(user.id)
  end
end
```

Now there are multiple places where I create new users. In one of those I want to not send mail to the user. So I did:

```
User.observers.disable :all do
  # Create user in here
end
```

This does not work, it still sends the email. I doubt sidekiq has anything to do with it. What is the best way to disable the observer for a block of code? For this part, I am open to disableabling the User observer or all observers.

Comment: Is there a certain attribute on your user that you could use in the Observer itself? `if user.email? #...`

Comment: under what conditions do you want to disable the observer? if it's something tied to the state of the user, you could just have a guard clause in the observer to return early and skip the email. Just trying to think of a way to bypass it without disabling observers if that's not working.

Comment: If the user is created by SSO, there is no domain in the users relation that indicates that though. What about disabling mailers in a  block?